# Odd Interface Syntax

Tags: c#, syntax

All, I have come across the following property and object declaration. The first returns an interface, and the second I am not too sure about

```
public IConfig this[int index]
{
    get { return (IConfig)configList[index]; }
}

object IList.this[int index]
{
    get { return configList[index]; }
    set {  }
}
```

I have never seen this type of declaration, namely the `public IConfig this[int index]` with square brackets and the odd use of `this` and `object IList.this[int index]`. Can some one explain the two notations?

I have attempted to look in the books I have, and use Google but I am unsure what I am searching for. Thanks for your time.

Edit. These are in a class that inherits as follows

```
public class ConfigCollection : ICollection, IEnumerable, IList
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: That's an [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2549tw02.aspx) and an [explicit interface implemenation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx) (of an indexer) respectively.

Comment: object is to denote that any type could be used to return from the property.  Square brackets are often associated with Arrays, Dictionaries and other collection types.

Comment: The idea was to make a "list-like" object, but one that lets you retrieve items type-safely. The explicit interface implementation is there to, effectively, "hide" the non-type-safe indexer unless it's needed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is called an [`indexer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2549tw02.aspx) and allows you to do `instance[1];` when getting an element from your object. You can have a look at this answer on [`implementing IList`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1176502/1069200) as a reference

Answer (score 3):

I also want to add one more detail to Johan's post - you actually have 2 indexers going on in that class because of the multiple interfaces.

The indexer that is implemented from `IList` is being declared explicitly, hence this one will not be invoked by default.  If you want to use the `IList` version of the indexer, you would need to do this:

```
ConfigCollection thisCollection = GetCollectionItems();

// this invokes the IList.this indexer....
var firstItem = ((IList)thisCollection)[0];  

// this invokes the other indexer
var firstItemAsIConfig = thisCollection[0];
```

I think the `IList.this` indexer is redundant, based on the code you've shared with us.

Answer (score 1):

Say you had

```
public class MyAggregate
{
  private List<String> _things;
  public MyAggregate()
  {
    _things = new List<String>();
  }
}
```

So you could add

```
public String GetItem(int argIndex)
{
  return _things[argIndex];
}
```

and

```
public void SetItem(int argIndex, String argValue)
{
  _things[argIndex] = argValue;
}
```

and then access through `myAggregate.GetItem(0)` to get it and `myAggregate.SetItem(0,"Thing")` to set it.

or you could add

```
public string this[int argIndex] 
{
  get {return _things[argIndex];}
  set { _things[argIndex] = value;}
}
```

and access it through `myAggregate[0]` to get it and `myAggregate[0] = "Thing"` to set it.

The latter tends to feel more natural and you don't have to come up with two method names every time.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Have a great weekend... :]